# "Statement is Not Valid In a Namespace" in button-click handler

Tags: vb.net

My `Private Sub btnDisplay` click-event procedure is telling me(blue line error message on `btnDisplay` row):

> "Statement is Not Valid In a Namespace"`.

I've added `End Sub` and `End Class` and still got the same error message.

```
Public Class frmMain

   Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()

   End Sub
End Class

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    ' displays D's 3 comments

    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(txtChoice.Text, intChoice)


    If intChoice = 1 Then
        lblComment.Text = "Not Exactly"
    Else
        If intChoice = 2 Then
            lblComment.Text = "No, Were You Listening?"
        Else
            If intChoice = 3 Then
                lblComment.Text = "This Is Close"
            Else
                lblComment.Text = "N/A"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: _"I've added End Sub and End Class and still got the same error mssg."_ If you have raelly added it, why don't you show that code instead? Because here it is clearly missing.

Comment: Your `end class` has to be after all your subs... after all your class contains all your subs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's exactly what the error message is saying - method declaration like `Private Sub` is not a valid statement inside a namespace (read: outside of a class/module). Try this:

```
Public Class frmMain

  Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                                            Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                                         Handles btnDisplay.Click
    'your code goes here
  End Sub

End Class
```